# scrollTop not scrolling all the way on iOS devices

Tags: javascript, scroll

This:

```js
scrollableContainer.scrollTop = bottomElement.offsetTop;
```

(Where `bottomElement` is an element at the bottom of my page)

Doesn't seem to work properly on iOS devices. As you can see [in this recorded session](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JG1XNHR7ob4SWcJoDZgENo3jJoEazGxF/view?usp=sharing), it doesn't scroll down all the way to the bottom.

I don't have this problem with desktops.

[Here is my site](https://bot.typebot.io/landing-page-hero-en) if you'd like to test it yourself.

Comment: How is your question going to remain useful for other users with a similar problem after you fix it on your website?

Comment: Why do you think it is specific to my website?